# Reset the initial state of an element after some DOM manimulations (native js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to save the initial state of my Element (with all childs) and after that do some actions ( initialize scrollbar plugin ) and after the window resize event I want to clear these changed values to the saved "pure" element and after that re-initialize the scrollbar plugin (I just want to do a scrollbar element responsive with the different views).

I tried to use `.cloneNode(true),  jquery.clone(true) and jquery.replaceWith()` but it doesn't work for me becase these methods somehow keep all chages that was done before. So I can't get the saved initial HTML. 
Should I user outerHTML maybe? Thanks for any help.

```
var GLOBAL_rawScrollBarNode;
var GLOBAL_scrollBarParent;

$(document).ready(function($){
      GLOBAL_rawScrollBarNode = $('#scrollbar3').clone();

      GLOBAL_scrollBarParent = $('.portfolio-scroll-box')[0];



      portfolioScrollbarOfDeviceWidth();

    $(window).resize(function(){ 
        portfolioScrollbarOfDeviceWidth();
});



function portfolioScrollbarOfDeviceWidth() {
    var documentWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

    //GLOBAL_scrollBarParent.removeChild(document.getElementById('scrollbar3'));
    //GLOBAL_scrollBarParent.appendChild(GLOBAL_rawScrollBarNode);

    GLOBAL_scrollBarParent.replaceWith(GLOBAL_rawScrollBarNode[0])


    var $scrollBarEl = $('#scrollbar3');

    setTimeout(() => {
        if (documentWidth < 942) {
            console.log("XXX")
            var bar = $scrollBarEl.tinyscrollbar({ axis: 'x',sizethumb: 135 });
            console.log(bar);
        } else {
            console.log("YYY")
            var bar = $scrollBarEl.tinyscrollbar({ axis: 'y',sizethumb: 135 });
            console.log(bar);
        }
    }, 2000)

}
```

P.S.  in case of the outerHTML of the saved ELEMENT and after that assign it like innerHTML to it's parent - it works fine. But I want to know how this issue can be resolved in other more elegant way :)